# Age of Mythology via Hamachi

Tags: hamachi, age-of-mythology

Ok, So I am trying to play Age of Mythology with my friends on a VPN with Hamachi...  My friends managed to connect to each other without doing anything extra, but I can't connect using the same way. I tried some things including overriding so that it uses my Hamachi IP address, disconnecting from other connections, opening AOM, then re-connecting but nothing. It is giving me the 15 second timeout. Any help please??

Comment: Why dont you just use the in-game multiplayer feature instead of an unstable third party program?

Comment: actually, I will try voobly, any feedback about that?

Comment: But my question remains why? The only reason one would want to use a program like that is to use a modded mp game. So a game which doesn't support multiplayer without a mod. Age of Mythology has an excellent multiplayer feature which works just fine. So once again, Why would you want to use an unstable third party program?

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma Probably pirated copy

Comment: The reason I don't want to use the main multiplayer feature is because I can't due to my ISP. Yeah I should change ISP but not everyone in my household agrees. So I had to find another way. Voobly works just as fune.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voobly. This software works great. Opening up a game room in the lobby, have your friends join and then you're good to go. The only problem is that when the game opens up, Voobly will take control of your mouse to set up the game, an when this is done you must take control back by switching windows using Alt+Tab or Windows+Tab, then back again.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty low tech workaround that worked for me on the older versions of hamachi (e.g. 1.0.1.5) which have now been shut down.

1. Disconnect your ethernet cable (or disable your local network connection)
2. Start Age of Mythology
3. Reconnect your ethernet cable (or enable your local network connection)
4. Host/Join a game

Each player will have to perform these steps when playing over hamachi. Basically the problem with Age of Mythology and hamachi is that it always prioritizes your LAN network connection, so even with hamachi running you'll have a LAN IP in the lobby. By disconnecting your ethernet cable and then starting the game you force Age of Mythology to use your hamachi network as your main network. The game only performs this check on startup so reconnecting/enabling your network connection after the game has started will still use hamachi as the main network while the game is running.

**NOTE:** From what I remember this will NOT work on Age of Mythology: Titans but that may have changed with the latest version of hamachi (version >= 2.0).

You can find all the details of this workaround [here](http://www.thegameengine.org/age-of-mythology/age-of-mythology-over-hamachi/).